# Change the time of goroutine sleeping

Tags: go, process, sleep, goroutine

In `Go` I can write such code for creating a gorouting that sleeps `5` sec.

```
func sleep(link chan interface{}){
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("I've slept for 5 sec")
    link <- struct {}{}
}

func main() {
    var link = make(chan interface{})
    go sleep(link)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    // here I want to change the remaining sleeping time of `sleep` goroutine to 0.5 sec
    <- link
}
```

What if in `main` function I change my mind and decide that the sleeper should sleep not `5` sec but `3`. How can it done if goroutine already started to sleep (and sleeping, for example, for `1` sec)?

**UPDATE**

I mean is there *something* whereby I can manage that unique goroutine while it sleeps. Like giving commands to it about decreasing or increasing time of sleep:

```
func main() {
    // ...
    time.Sleep(1)
    something.ManageRemainingTime(10)
    time.Sleep(5)
    something.ManageRemainingTime(100)
    time.Sleep(8)
    something.ManageRemainingTime(0.5)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need a way to "wakeup" a sleeping goroutine, you could use `sync.Once` to ensure your function only gets called once, and then return a channel so you can set a sooner "trigger time", so something this:

```
func sleep(callback func(), seconds int) chan int {
    once := sync.Once{}
    wakeup := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for sleep := range wakeup {
            go func() {
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleep) * time.Second)
                once.Do(callback)
            }()
        }
    }()
    wakeup <- seconds
    return wakeup
}


func main() {
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(1)
        t := time.Now()
        wakeup := sleep(func() {
            fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
            wg.Done()
        }, 5)
        wakeup <- 2
        wg.Wait()
        fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BRNtaBPKpLW

Comment: Do you create several goroutines?  Yes. It's not what I ment. Because I wanted something whereby I can manage that unique goroutine.  Like giving commands to it  "Sleep 50 sec", after 1 sec another command "sleep 30 sec" and after 5 sec "sleep 0.5 sec".

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use a [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) object. Specifically one created with [`WithTimeout`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithTimeout).

The context object provides a way of sending a "cancel" signal to a worker. In this case your worker is not really doing anything, but still fits the paradigm.

Example would be:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func sleep(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    sctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 5*time.Second)
    tStart := time.Now()
    <-sctx.Done() // will sit here until the timeout or cancelled
    tStop := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("Slept for %s\n", tStop.Sub(tStart))
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go sleep(ctx, &wg)

    if true {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        cancelFunc()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

<sup>https://play.golang.org/p/2Krx4PsxFKL</sup>

Change the `if true {` to `if false {` and you can see the `Slept for ...` change.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use a [`timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer). You can call [`Stop()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop) on a timer, but this stops it without waking up whatever is waiting on it. So you then use [`Reset()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Reset) to set it to a new value, specifically `0`, which triggers it immediately.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func sleep(wg *sync.WaitGroup) *time.Timer {
    timer := time.NewTimer(5 * time.Second)
    go func() {
        tStart := time.Now()
        <-timer.C
        tStop := time.Now()
        fmt.Printf("Slept for %s\n", tStop.Sub(tStart))
        wg.Done()
    }()
    return timer
}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    timer := sleep(&wg)
    if true {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        if timer.Stop() {
            timer.Reset(0)
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

<sup>https://play.golang.org/p/b3I65kAujR4</sup>

Change the `if true {` to `if false {` and you can see the `Slept for ...` change.